# Unity3d. GetComponent method not working on android buid

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in Unity3d when running on Android.

The script does not find the component in the object found by the tag.

What I do:

1)  I'm looking for an object by tag in the 'Awake()' method:

```
GameObject timeLineSpanGo = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(KeyStringConstants.InitiativeSpanTag);
```

*At this step GameObject was found successfully (timeLineSpanGo != null).*

2) I'm trying to get a component from '**timeLineSpanGo**':

```
TimeLine = timeLineSpanGo.GetComponent<TimeLine>();
```

(Here '**TimeLine**' is the field in the GameManager.)

*At this step GameObject - not found (TimeLine == zero).*

Therefore, the 'GetComponent()' method does not find the desired component.

*update:*

Interesting. If I try to find the 'FindObjectOfType()' after checking, then the object was found. But in my project only one object of this type.

```
TimeLine = timeLineSpanGo.GetComponent <TimeLine>(); 
if (TimeLine == null)
{
      TimeLine = FindObjectOfType<TimeLine>();
}
```

That is, the component exists in memory, but is not found by the 'GetComponent<>()' method of the parent object.

The error appears only when starting on the Android device.
When starting from Editor, an error does not occur.

- Unity version - 2017.2.0f3 Personal
- Android version is 7.1.2
- Android  device = Nokia 6 (TA-1021)

Comment: Is the error there when you build for Windows?

Comment: Is the component on a child of the found object? Is it actually on that object? The FindObjectOfType will find it wherever it is so maybe ot is not on that object. GetComponent is too common snd simple to be buggy after 10 years in the engine.

Comment: @Everts this's comonent of the found object, not on a child. yes, actualy, I checked it again.